# How does versioning in the Rust Prelude work?

Tags: rust

My question is regarding the `std::prelude`.

`std::prelude` in Rust 2021 includes `super::v1::*` (**v1** of the Rust prelude) and `core::prelude::rust_2021::*`.

At this point, all versions of Rust (2015-2024) include **v1** of the prelude.

In order to use common core modules for future versions of Rust that are different than **v1**, and without affecting the current (and previous) version(s) of Rust using **v1**, is the plan to do a simple versioning system like **v1**, **v2**, ..., **v[x]**, or is there another path forward?

Comment: `std::prelude::v1` refers to the prelude of Rust v1.0.0 The other preludes are versioned by edition.

Answer (score 0):

Before Rust's 1.0 release, there was just the `std::prelude`; there was no versioning at all. Since development was rapid and the language was highly volatile, it wouldn't make sense to think about keeping prior versions working; changes were made directly as needed. [The Rust 0.12.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/0.12.0/std/prelude/index.html) looks much different than what we know today.

Once planning started for a 1.0 release, some thought had to be put towards backwards compatibility and how portions of the language would grow over time. It was already known that the prelude was likely to change in the future so it was trimmed down and thrown into a versioned module. And that's how [the Rust 1.0.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/prelude/index.html) got to be named `std::prelude::v1`.

The prelude was unchanged for the Rust 2018 edition so it stayed as `std::prelude::v1`.

When the Rust 2021 edition was in the process of finalizing development, some additions were to be made to the prelude: ultimately adding `FromIterator`, `TryFrom`, and `TryInto`. Was this going to be `std::prelude::v2`? No. A whole new versioning scheme for Rust had been developed since `v1` was created: the edition system. It was time to retroactively update the prelude to reflect the edition being used. So in the midst of 2021:

- [The Rust 1.52.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.52.0/std/prelude/index.html) added `rust_2015`, `rust_2018`, and `rust_2021` as experimental modules
- [The Rust 1.55.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.55.0/std/prelude/index.html) stabilized the edition'd modules
- [The Rust 1.56.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.56.0/std/prelude/index.html) was the first updated prelude to be used by default for new crates as Rust 2021 edition was released

As we venture forth into the future, [the Rust 1.62.0 prelude](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.62.0/std/prelude/index.html) has already added a `rust_2024` experimental module. It will probably not be stabilized until much closer to the Rust 2024 edition release, but it already indicates that the path forward is clear.

So no, there will not be a `std::prelude::v2` anytime soon; the prelude will follow editions.

---

See also:

- [Preludes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/names/preludes.html) in the Rust Reference
- [Tracking issue #85684](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/3114-prelude-2021.md): Edition-specific preludes